# Trying to download intel UMC library for media encoding

Tags: encoding, media, intel

I am trying to encode some media from YUV frames using the Intel IPP library. The example code which I [found here](http://software.intel.com/file/23813)
uses headers from Intel's Unified Media Classes.

I cannot for the life of me figure out where to get these headers. I downloaded and installed the 30 day trial for Intel Parallel Studio XE which includes the IPP library and headers but I cannot find the other headers needed to compile this test code.

Can anyone tell me where to get these libraries and headers.

Answer (score 1):

I believe these are the droids you were looking for:

[Intel Media SDK](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/vcsource-tools-media-sdk/)

[Intel IPP](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-ipp/)